# Android program how to show pictures with time interval?

Tags: java, android

I'm totally new in programing in java. I made one app for android that show 1 of 16 posible pictures based on the combination of 4 digital inputs on IOIO board. I made this using a IF sentence (maybe this is not the best way but works), now my question is: I want to show not only one picture but a secuence of pictures (4 or 5) to show like a animation.

Something like this:

```
if ((((val1 == false)&& (val2 == true)) && (val3 == true)) && (val4 == true)){
                        imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.in1);
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.in2);
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.in3);
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.in4);
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    }
```

I try with:

```
Thread.sleep(100);
```

but I have a error when I try to compile
Also try with:

```
    try {
 Thread.sleep(100);
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But the app dont work. Any sugestion???

This is the code of my app:

```
package com.example.mycar;

import ioio.lib.api.DigitalInput;
import ioio.lib.api.exception.ConnectionLostException;
import ioio.lib.util.BaseIOIOLooper;
import ioio.lib.util.IOIOLooper;
import ioio.lib.util.android.IOIOActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends IOIOActivity {

boolean val1, val2, val3, val4;
ImageView imagen;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imagen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.estado);
}

class Looper extends BaseIOIOLooper{

    DigitalInput entrada1, entrada2, entrada3, entrada4;

    @Override
    protected void setup() throws ConnectionLostException,
            InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        entrada1 = ioio_.openDigitalInput(37, DigitalInput.Spec.Mode.PULL_UP);
        entrada2 = ioio_.openDigitalInput(38, DigitalInput.Spec.Mode.PULL_UP);
        entrada3 = ioio_.openDigitalInput(39, DigitalInput.Spec.Mode.PULL_UP);
        entrada4 = ioio_.openDigitalInput(40, DigitalInput.Spec.Mode.PULL_UP);
    }

    @Override
    public void loop() throws ConnectionLostException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        val1 = entrada1.read();
        val2 = entrada2.read();
        val3 = entrada3.read();
        val4 = entrada4.read();
        mostrarentradas(val1, val2, val3, val4);
        Thread.sleep(20);
    }

}

@Override
protected IOIOLooper createIOIOLooper() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Looper();
}
private void mostrarentradas(final boolean val1, final boolean val2, final boolean val3,
        final boolean val4) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()

            {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if ((((val1 == false)&& (val2 == true)) && (val3 == true)) && (val4 == true)){
                        imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.in1);
                    }
                    if ((((val1 == false)&& (val2 == false)) && (val3 == true)) && (val4 == true)){
                        imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.in8);
                    }
                    if ((((val1 == false)&& (val2 == false)) && (val3 == false)) && (val4 == true)){
                        imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.in11);
                    }
                    if ((((val1 == false)&& (val2 == false)) && (val3 == false)) && (val4 == false)){
                        imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.in14);
                    }
                    if ((((val1 == false)&& (val2 == true)) && (val3 == false)) && (val4 == true)){
                        imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.in16);
                    }
                    if ((((val1 == false)&& (val2 == true)) && (val3 == true)) && (val4 == false)){
                        imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.in22);
                    }
                    if ((((val1 == false)&& (val2 == false)) && (val3 == true)) && (val4 == false)){
                        imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.in25);
                    }
                    if ((((val1 == false)&& (val2 == true)) && (val3 == false)) && (val4 == false)){
                        imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.in29);
                    }
                    if ((((val1 == true)&& (val2 == false)) && (val3 == true)) && (val4 == true)){
                        imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.in2);
                        //Thread.sleep(100);
                        imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.in3);
                    }
                    if ((((val1 == true)&& (val2 == false)) && (val3 == false)) && (val4 == true)){
                        imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.in18);
                    }
                    if ((((val1 == true)&& (val2 == false)) && (val3 == true)) && (val4 == false)){
                        imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.in20);
                    }
                    if ((((val1 == true)&& (val2 == false)) && (val3 == false)) && (val4 == false)){
                        imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.in27);
                    }
                    if ((((val1 == true)&& (val2 == true)) && (val3 == false)) && (val4 == true)){
                        imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.in4);
                    }
                    if ((((val1 == true)&& (val2 == true)) && (val3 == false)) && (val4 == false)){
                        imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.in30);
                    }
                    if ((((val1 == true)&& (val2 == true)) && (val3 == true)) && (val4 == false)){
                        imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.in5);
                    }
                    if ((((val1 == true)&& (val2 == true)) && (val3 == true)) && (val4 == true)){
                        imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.vwg0);
                    }

                }

            }
    );
}
```

}

Comment: Time to read up on threading. If you put the UI thread to sleep, of course your app will stop responding. Look into runnables and handlers.

Comment: `but I have a error` `But the app dont work` Surely you have more details than that for us to go off of. You haven't told is *anything* about the error or how it "dont work". Please add details if you want an answer.

Comment: Just as a side node you can put together many if statements. For example you only need to check `val1 == true` once and you can then handly in its body all cases where `val1 == true` and in the else all cases where `val1 == false`. Moreover use `else if` instead of many `if` statements, since only one can be true. The remaining cases are then skipped once you found the right one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe use `postDelayed` method and `Runnable` for it? creating separated Thread for it is too much work for this, also you can't update View outside UI thread

```
imagen.postDelayed(new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run(){
        imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.in1);
    }
}, 1000); //1000ms delay
```

inside `run` you might set again `postDelayed` method